# Unable to open Excel file after executing Program

Tags: c#

I am adding some data to Excel file using C# Window form application. But after executing the program, to open excel file i need to close the Window form otherwise i am not able to open not only the excel file to which i added the data but also the any excel file. when i tried to open any excel file without closing Window form application it was not showing any data and cells(just a blank screen).

i need to close my appilcation to view the excel files.Even at the i wrote the code for releasing the COM objects.

```
        workbook = appExl.Workbooks.Open(Excel_file, 0,false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
        workbook.Save();            
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ShtRange);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(NwSheet);           
        workbook.Close(true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
        appExl.Quit();
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appExl);
```

so please help me how to open excel file without closing application after execution?

Comment: If you re working with Excel 2007 or later you can avoid all this COM stuff by using the Open XML SDK

Comment: My link talks about [C# excel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/198572/Summarize-C-Control-Excel-Skills) by using Interop.Excel. However, I also like you to have a trial with Open XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code in which i write to excel sheet using C# and it works great.Use  folllowing namespaces 
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

check this out

```
   Excel.Application XlApp = null;
        Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
        Excel.Worksheet Ws = null;
        Excel.Range Range1 = null;
        Excel.Worksheet X = null;

        XlApp = new Excel.Application();
        XlApp.Visible = true;
        workbook = XlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
        Ws = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];
        XlApp.WindowState = XlWindowState.xlMaximized;


                Ws = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];

                Ws.Activate();
                Ws.Name = "MyFirstSheet";



              int rowIndex = 1; int columnIndex = 2;
               xlApp.Cells(rowIndex, columnIndex) = "Blah"
```

Comment: I want to add data to already existing excel file. the code above also works for that?

Comment: The OP's problem is about the application holding the Excel file open even after the workbook has been closed. Perhaps you should include your code which _closes_ the Excel document.

Answer (score 0):

try this first open an existing file(xls).then Add worksheet to it as much as you want and write data to it

```
            Missing _value = Missing.Value;
            string strtemp = "C:\\MyExcel.xls";
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook Wtemp = XlApp.Workbooks.Open(strtemp, _value, _value, _value, _value, _value, _value, _value, _value, _value, _value, _value,  _value, _value, _value);
Wtemp = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
```

Then by using the above function you can write data to it...